# artifacts on all my objects

Tags: objects, artifacts

All my objects in all Layers have these kinds of artifacts, anyone know why that may be?, when i hit "P" to play blender game they dissapear, but its super enoying to work with when you are texturing and so on[image: Strange lines]

Comment: Probably something to do with that massive end clip value, but could also be some AO setting. Could you upload the blend?

Comment: omg thanks did not think about that end clip value! I changed it down to 1000 and now it looks normal, thanks for spotting that, feel so stupid now xD

Answer (score 3):

Your *End Clip* value (in the middle right of your screenshot) is extremely high.

Computers have [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) calculating wide ranges of floating point (decimal) numbers with extreme precision and often end up with slightly inaccurate results. If you narrow down the range it has to calculate (by decreasing the End Clip), those artifacts will disappear.